# How to store data correspondingly with user id token React Native and Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-authentication, token, react-native-firebase

I'm a newbie in React Native and struggling in storing data within each user logging in the app

I've successfully added Firebase google authentication into my app which is a trip app. (I use react-native-firebase library)

Here are the data in the flow:

```
1. User chooses locations
2. User choose date, name
3. App generates a list of trips for users ( trips are stored in Redux, displayed by FlatList)
```

Since, we use only Google authentication, we also have the token of that user and the `uid` of Firebase authentication as well.

*So how can we store that token, so next time when user open the app again, it will sign in silently? And how can I attach those lists of trips for each user ? Like when user login again, he/she will see his/her trips made before*

I'd be happy to learn articles or reading resources for understanding the working progress. Like what requirements are( cloud, data base,..), or what stages needed to be done... (code is not required)

**Please help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After logging in, you can save the user token with redux, AsyncStorage, redux-persist, etc.

To bypass the login you can, for example, set a `StartScreen`(I suggest using `react-navigation`) where you check in redux if the `uid` of the user is set and if it's set you can navigate to `HomeScreen` otherwise you can navigate to `AuthScreen`.

To connect the user with his trips you can save the `trips` on the Cloud Firestore and add to the `trip` object a param containing the `uid` of the user. In this way when a user login you can also send a request (with the `uid`) to Firebase and get the associated trips.

Comment: Thanks Marco. Can I ask 1 more question: when the user see his trips, we need to request from the cloud. What's the difference if we request from the realtime database?

Comment: And later on, when we add the trip sharing feature, we need to do that with cloud storage right?

Comment: @Marwin I suggest you read this post: https://medium.com/datadriveninvestor/realtime-database-vs-cloud-firestore-which-database-is-suitable-for-your-mobile-app-87e11b56f50f

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend you learn about how to manage the state of you application. What you are looking for it's a state containers like Redux.

Here I let you where you can find it: https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started.

After that you can store in the memory of your app creating a DB, or saving it with the AsyncStorage: https://reactnative.dev/docs/asyncstorage

Comment: Thanks for the help. But, I alreay added the Redux store into my app. I'm using Firebase database. And trying to use Redux-persist to store the data. What I need is a general instructions of the steps required, not about how to use those tools